# How to set VPN password automatically while installing VPN connection without any user interaction?

Tags: ios8, vpn

I have been trying to create VPN connection programmatically, I referred to this [link](http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/08/03/configure-and-manage-vpn-connections-programmatically-in-ios-8/)

Its working fine but when user installs the profile, its asking VPN password again. I’m not interested in asking the user to set the password. I need to set password automatically without getting it from user. How to do this? (I saw some app that has done this already).

Comment: I set password wrongly there, after following this link http://ramezanpour.net/post/2014/09/26/how-to-get-persistent-references-to-keychain-items-in-ios/ its working fine for me.